# When I typed console.log to my browser, why does Google Chrome not showing me the result?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I'm a blind learner. I want to test an expression like

```js
console.log(1 + 2);

function myFunction() {
  var a = 1 + 2;
}
console.log(myFunction());
```

But it is not showing me anything (not even errors).

I don't know if that is an accessibility issue.

My browser is up-to-date.

Any help will be greatly accepted.

Comment: Because `myFunction` doesn't return anything.

Comment: But when I type a expression such as console.log(1+2); it does the same thing.

Comment: function myFunction(){
  return 1+2;
}

Comment: `console.log(myFunction());` amounts to `var returnValue = myFunction();` then `console.log(returnValue);` but since the function doesn't do anything besides declaring a variable, assigning 3 to it, then discarding it, and no value is returned, `returnValue` will be `undefined`, and logging just that has no effect.

Comment: Everyone, the OP is saying `console.log(1 + 2)` does not report anything to a blind person. All of this discussion about `myFunction` not returning anything is irrelevant if that simple log does not work for a visually impaired person.

Comment: @TobyHarnish console.log printed out what is inside. a) (1+2) => is an calculation and b) console.log(myFunction()) => is an function

Comment: The first expression should print out 3. console.log(1+2); instead, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Where in the browser are you typing this? Where is your AT trying to read the result from?

Comment: @HereticMonkey  That might be the issue indeed, but based on the question or title or even tag it's not apparent.  Maybe the OP might make this a tad more obvious, "accessibility issue" could mean anything.

Comment: you probably want to stop using the term "showing" and use "screen reader telling" maybe.... it will be less confusing

Comment: I am typing my expressions in the console edit box. I don't know where to look since my screen reader (JAWS) doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: @TobyHarnish maybe its an accessibility issue, not js issue.

Comment: It happens that I've been working on making my website more accessible, so I had NVDA installed and ready to go. I hope that my answer reads okay for you; let me know if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating and using developer tools is difficult at first with a screen reader, but it doesn't take long to get used to it.

First, have a read of this [document from Google on devtools shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts) you will find there are loads of shortcuts that you can use. This makes it easy to get used to navigating the console.

### How to navigate in your example.

What is confusing when you are not used to it is that the text that is logged to the console is attached to the line and character declaration (so for example it may read "VM50:1 3", explained below)

So in your example above you navigate to the previous item (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) to get `undefined` as that is still what `console.log(1+2)` will return.

Then if you press the <kbd>Up arrow</kbd> it will focus a link and announce "link vm50:1 3" where "link vm50:1" is line and character number and "3" is the answer.

An easier way to understand this is to log some words to the console instead, if you log "I like cheese, it is yummy" you will get something like "VM50:1 I like cheese, it is yummy"

One thing that can be confusing is when you get an error that results in a stack trace (as we are reading from the bottom to the top). For that I tend to spam the <kbd>up arrow</kbd> until I don't hear "at" and get a script name as that will announce the error as well.

Finally try navigating via links (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> in NVDA) as that can also be a quick way to get to errors (although can be confusing if you get a stack trace as above).

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome does not make it easy for a visually impaired person to see the result of a `console.log()` statement in their Developer Tools Console.

I used NVDA in my experiments. Your experience in other screen readers may be different.

1. I entered `console.log(1+2)` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

   This read "undefined", as that is the return value of `console.log()`.
3. I pressed <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> once.

   This read "three".

I can't imagine the experience of reading anything more complex would be. Good luck.